# Value not right while doing cumprod() to get cumulative returns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `.csv` file in the following link : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Ak0_niMCNyPN3S1fq8hLDu5A7Dt-W3Bp?usp=sharing, as well as an `test.xlsx`, where I reached my desired solution.

My problem is that when I do the `.cumprod()` command in python,I get the value in the last cell that is `10.30059`, and while I do the same steps in excel I get my desired output that is : `5.75`. Obviously I am doing it wrong in python, but I am unable to find my mistake.
this is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date
import numpy as np 
ibov=pd.read_csv("ibov.csv",delimiter=";")

ibov=ibov.replace("-",np.nan)

ibov['IBOV']=ibov['IBOV'].str.replace(',','.')
ibov['IBOV']=pd.to_numeric(ibov['IBOV'])
ibov['Data']= pd.to_datetime(ibov['Data'],dayfirst=True)



ibov= ibov[(ibov.Data >= pd.Timestamp(date(1998, 6, 1)))]
ibov=ibov.set_index('Data')

ibov=ibov.pct_change()

ibov=ibov+1

a=ibov.cumprod()
```

I tried changing the `np.nan` for `0`, as well as the method of `pct_change` for filling missing values but it was in vain.

OBS : I used the starting date as  06/1998

Comment: Why do you add 1 after pct change?

Comment: when you are calculating the cumulative annual return of stocks based on the daily return, you have the following : annual return = ((1+return day 1) *(1+return day 2)*(...)*(1 + return day n) - 1)

Comment: Dont you need the cummulative difference instead of percentage change for calculation of return?

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/annualized-total-return.asp

Comment: you could make the (last price - first price)/ first price to get the return of the period. But I need the daily variations for another part of my program

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure both of your calculations are incorrect. The correct formula to calculate cumulative returns is cumprod(returns + 1) - 1. You forgot to subtract one at the end.

Check it out:

```
    import pandas as pd
    
    ibov=pd.read_csv("ibov.csv") # getting the  raw prices
    ibov.head()

        Unnamed: 0  date    ibov
    0   1   1998-06-02  10150.0
    1   2   1998-06-03  9855.0
    2   3   1998-06-04  10191.0
    3   4   1998-06-05  10369.0
    4   5   1998-06-08  10540.0

ibov = ibov.iloc[:,[1,2]] #excluding unnamed col
ibov.head()

date    ibov
0   1998-06-02  10150.0
1   1998-06-03  9855.0
2   1998-06-04  10191.0
3   1998-06-05  10369.0
4   1998-06-08  10540.0

ibov['ibov'] = pd.to_numeric(ibov['ibov'])
ibov['pct'] = (ibov['ibov'].pct_change())+1 # pct_change + 1
ibov['cum_ret'] = ibov['pct'].cumprod() - 1 #cumprod - 1

ibov.tail()

    date    ibov    pct cum_ret
5462    2020-06-30  95055.82    0.992902    8.365105
5463    2020-07-01  96203.20    1.012071    8.478148
5464    2020-07-02  96234.96    1.000330    8.481277
5465    2020-07-03  96764.85    1.005506    8.533483
5466    2020-07-06  98937.16    1.022449    8.747503
```

The cummulative return ate the last date is 8.7475.

you can confirm this  by:

```
(ibov.iloc[-1,1] - ibov.iloc[0,1]) / ibov.iloc[0,1]    # finalPrice - initialPrice / initialPrice

8.747503448275863
```

Oh, I forgot to mention that I previously removed all rows containing “-“ . And a best practice would be performing mathematical operations using log returns instead of arithmetic returns